# Que signifie « à un an » ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, syntaxe

Je me demandais ce que signifie la phrase suivante :

*Je revois ta sœur à un an.*

Cela me paraît bizarre de voir la préposition « à » ici, c’est pourquoi je ne sais pas s’il s’agit d’un événement futur (je reverrai ta sœur dans un an) ou bien si l’action est déjà survenue.

Comment: Comme d'habitude, un peu de contexte permet (phrases précédentes et/ou suivante) permet toujours de trouver plus facilement le sens exact d'une phrase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

L'enfant ressemble à la sœur de quelqu'un (à sa tante peut-être) à l'âge d'un an.  La famille se ressemble et la ressemblance est frappante dans ce cas.  Autrement dit :

Regarde la petite, c'est comme si c'était ta sœur quand elle avait un an.

On dirait ta sœur à un an.

Comment: c'est clairement une possibilité, mais difficile d'être affirmatif sans contexte.

Answer (score 2):

La réponse de [user livresque](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/51701/17649) n'envisage qu'une seule des deux  éventualités que le contexte pourrait justifier ;  l'autre est la suivante : « je me représente mentalement ta sœur quand elle avait un an ». Le contexte est important dans le choix d'interprétation (ce qui précède, ce qui suit).

- Je revois ta sœur à un an, elle était déjà très dégourdie, très curieuse, alors que cette enfant à laquelle tu la compare est plutôt en retard par rapport à elle ; c'est tout juste si elle a appris à marcher.

Comment: 3ème possibilité : avec un bébé de 6 mois, chez le pédiatre  qui s'adresse au grand frère (ou à la grande soeur) : "je revois ta soeur à un an", c'est à dire au prochain rendez-vous de suivi pédiatrique. Bon j'avoue c'est un peu tiré par les cheveux...mais possible.

Comment: « À » ne serait pas correct à mon avis; je n'ai jamais entendu que « dans un an » pour ce contexte.

Comment: Le sens ne serait pas le même : si le bébé a 6 mois et et doit être revu pour ses 1 an (donc 6 mois, donc), on pourrait dire aussi "pour ses 1 an" mais pas "dans un an".

Comment: @XouDo Selon ce contexte, oui, c'est une construction qui se tient mieux : on peut encore invoquer des tournures acceptées comme « il l'a examinée à deux ans, à cinq ans et à six ans pour la dernière fois » (par exemple) ; ça semble acceptable.